# Oracle PL/SQL Code will not compile, ORA-06550: line 96, column 3:PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have written the following PL/SQL code block and it uses a long array of 4 digit strings in the array.
The program block will loop over the array using the array(i) position as a query variable to return the the r_LDR_IORG record which is then printed with i, array(i), and r_LRD_IORG.PS_ORG_ID.

```
 1  DECLARE
 2    type array_t is varray(692) of varchar2(6);
 3    array array_t := array_t('0118','0118','01R1','01R1','01R2','01R2','01R4','01R4',
 4                  '01R5','01R5','01R7','01R7','03BB','03BB','03BB','03BB',
 5                  '03R3','03R4','03R8','0684','0684','0684','0685','0685',
 6                  '0685','06CN','06CN','06CN','06GG','06GG','0799','0799',
 7                  '079T','079T','079T','079T','07R1','07R1','07R1','07R1',
 8                  '07R3','07R3','07R3','07R3','07R5','07R5','07R5','07R5',
 9                  '07R6','07R6','07R6','07R6','07R7','07R7','07R7','07R7',
10                  '0954','0954','0954','0956','0956','0956','0959','0959',
11                  '0959','09ZZ','09ZZ','09ZZ','14R1','14R1','14R1','14R2',
12                  '14R2','14R2','16C4','16C4','16C4','16R3','16R3','16R5',
13                  '16R5','16R5','16R5','16R7','16R7','16R7','16U4','16U4',
14                  '16U4','16U4','1850','1850','1851','1852','1899','20R1',
15                  '20R1','20R2','20R2','2181','2181','2181','2181','2182',
16                  '2182','2182','2182','2184','2184','2184','2184','2186',
17                  '2186','2186','2186','23C1','23C1','23C1','23C1','23C1',
18                  '23C1','23C2','23C2','23C2','23C2','23C2','23C2','23FF',
19                  '23FF','23FF','23FF','23R1','23R1','23R1','23R1','23R1',
20                  '23R1','23R1','23R1','23R2','23R2','23R2','23R2','23R2',
21                  '23R2','23R2','23R2','23R3','23R3','23R3','23R3','23R3',
22                  '23R3','23R3','23R3','23R5','23R5','23R5','23R5','23R5',
23                  '23R5','23R5','23R5','23R6','23R6','23R6','23R6','23R6',
24                  '23R6','23R6','23R6','23R7','23R7','23R7','23R7','23R8',
25                  '23R8','23R8','23R8','23R8','23R8','23R8','23VP','23VP',
26                  '23VP','23VP','23X1','23X1','23X1','23X1','23X2','23X2',
27                  '23X2','23X2','23X3','23X3','23X3','23X3','23X4','23X4',
28                  '23X4','23X4','23XX','23XX','23XX','23XX','24MA','24MA',
29                  '24MA','24MB','24MB','24MB','24MG','24MG','24MQ','24MQ',
30                  '24MQ','24MR','24MR','24MR','26R2','26R2','26R4','26R4',
31                  '299T','299T','299T','29R1','29R1','29R1','29R2','29R2',
32                  '29R2','29R3','29R3','29R4','29R4','29R4','3071','3071',
33                  '3071','3071','3072','3072','3072','3072','3075','3075',
34                  '3075','3075','3083','3083','3083','3083','3084','3084',
35                  '3084','3084','30XB','30XB','30XB','30XB','32M2','32M2',
36                  '32M2','32M2','32M2','32M3','32M3','32M3','32M3','32M3',
37                  '32M4','32M4','32M4','32M4','32M4','32M5','32M5','32M5',
38                  '32M5','32M5','32M6','32M6','32M6','32M6','32M6','32M7',
39                  '32M7','32M7','32M7','32M7','32M8','32M8','32M8','32M8',
40                  '32M8','32MB','32MB','32MB','32MB','32MB','32MD','32MD',
41                  '32MD','32MD','32MD','32ME','32ME','32ME','32ME','32ME',
42                  '32MF','32MF','32MF','32MF','32MF','32MG','32MG','32MG',
43                  '32MG','32MG','32MH','32MH','32MH','32MH','32MH','32MJ',
44                  '32MJ','32MJ','32MJ','32MJ','32MK','32MK','32MK','32MK',
45                  '32MK','32ML','32ML','32ML','32ML','32ML','32MM','32MM',
46                  '32MM','32MM','32MM','32MN','32MN','32MN','32MN','32MN',
47                  '32MP','32MP','32MP','32MP','32MP','32MV','32MV','32MV',
48                  '32MV','32MV','32MW','32MW','32MW','32MW','32MW','32R2',
49                  '32R2','32R2','32R2','32R2','32R3','32R3','32R3','32R3',
50                  '32R3','32R4','32R4','32R4','32R4','32R4','32R5','32R5',
51                  '32R5','32R5','32R5','32R6','32R6','32R6','32R6','32R6',
52                  '32R7','32R7','32R7','32R7','32R7','32R8','32R8','32R8',
53                  '32R8','32R8','32RA','32RA','32RA','32RA','32RA','32RB',
54                  '32RB','32RB','32RB','32RB','32RC','32RC','32RC','32RC',
55                  '32RC','32RD','32RD','32RD','32RD','32RD','32RE','32RE',
56                  '32RE','32RE','32RE','32RF','32RF','32RF','32RF','32RF',
57                  '32RG','32RG','32RG','32RG','32RG','32RH','32RH','32RH',
58                  '32RH','32RH','32RJ','32RJ','32RJ','32RJ','32RJ','32RK',
59                  '32RK','32RK','32RK','32RK','32RL','32RL','32RL','32RL',
60                  '32RL','32RM','32RM','32RM','32RM','32RM','32RN','32RN',
61                  '32RN','32RN','32RN','32RP','32RP','32RP','32RP','32RP',
62                  '32RQ','32RQ','32RQ','32RQ','32RQ','32RW','32RW','32RW',
63                  '32RW','32RW','341R','341R','341R','35R1','35R1','35R1',
64                  '35R1','35R2','35R2','35R2','35R3','35R3','35R3','35R3',
65                  '39Z1','4175','4175','4175','4175','4176','4176','4176',
66                  '4176','4177','4177','4177','4177','4179','4179','4179',
67                  '4179','41U1','41U1','41U1','41U1','41U2','41U2','41U2',
68                  '41U2','41U3','41U3','41U3','41U3','41U4','41U4','41U4',
69                  '41U4','41Z1','41Z1','41Z1','41Z1','4290','4290','4290',
70                  '4290','4293','4293','4293','4293','42B7','42B7','42B7',
71                  '42N7','42N7','42N7','42N7','4350','4350','4350','4351',
72                  '4351','4351','4390','4390','4390','4390','4391','4391',
73                  '4391','4391','43C9','43C9','43C9','43C9','44R1','44R1',
74                  '44R1','44R1','46MM','46MM','46MM','46R1','46R1','46R1',
75                  '46R2','46R2','46R2','46R2','489B','489B','48R1','48R1',
76                  '48R3','48R3','5185','5185','5279','5279','5279','5297',
77                  '5297','5297','521U','521U','521U','52R1','52R1','52R1',
78                  '53R1','53R1','53R1','53R1','53R2','53R2','53R2','53R2',
79                  '53R4','53R4','53R4','53R4','53R6','53R6','53R6','53R6',
80                  '53R7','53R7','53R7','53R7','5480','5480','5481','5481',
81                  '5482','5482','5501','5501','5501','5501','5501','5501',
82                  '5501','5501','5501','5502','5502','5502','5502','5502',
83                  '5502','5502','5502','5502','5502','5503','5503','5503',
84                  '5503','5503','5503','5503','5503','5503','5503','55X6',
85                  '55X6','55X6','55X6','560X','560X','560X','560X','561X',
86                  '561X','561X','561X','56PP','56PP','56PP','56PP','62R2',
87                  '62R2','65BT','65BT','65Z1','65Z1','65Z1','2R88','2R88',
88                  '2S50','2S50','2S99','2S99','3E99','3E99','3E99','3E99',
89                  '3EL1','3EL1','3EL1','3EL1'); -- Initialise it
90  BEGIN
91     for i in 1..array.count loop
92      for r_LRD_IORG IN (select * from LRDLicnse.LRD_IORG where IORG_TYP_DSC = 'BRANCH' and Record_status = 'A' and LGCY_IORG_ID = array(i)) loop   
93        dbms_output.put_line(i, array(i), r_LRD_IORG.PS_ORG_ID);
94      end loop;
95     end loop;
96  END
97  /
```

After trying to compile the code block and run it I get the following error messages.

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
DECLARE
   type array_t is varray(692) of varchar2(6);
   array array_t := array_t('0118','0118','01R1','01R1','01R2','01R2','01R4','01R4',
                '01R5','01R5','01R7','01R7','03BB','03BB','03BB','03BB',
                '03R3','03R4','03R8','0684','0684','0684','0685','0685',
                '0685','06CN','06CN','06CN','06GG','06GG','0799','0799',
                '079T','079T','079T','079T','07R1','07R1','07R1','07R1',
                '07R3','07R3','07R3','07R3','07R5','07R5','07R5','07R5',
                '07R6','07R6','07R6','07R6','07R7','07R7','07R7','07R7',
                '0954','0954','0954','0956','0956','0956','0959','0959',
                '0959','09ZZ','09ZZ','09ZZ','14R1','14R1','14R1','14R2',
                '14R2','14R2','16C4','16C4','16C4','16R3','16R3','16R5',
                '16R5','16R5','16R5','16R7','16R7','16R7','16U4','16U4',
                '16U4','16U4','1850','1850','1851','1852','1899','20R1',
                '20R1','20R2','20R2','2181','2181','2181','2181','2182',
                '2182','2182','2182','2184','2184','2184','2184','2186',
                '2186','2186','2186','23C1','23C1','23C1','23C1','23C1',
                '23C1','23C2','23C2','23C2','23C2','23C2','23C2','23FF',
                '23FF','23FF','23FF','23R1','23R1','23R1','23R1','23R1',
                '23R1','23R1','23R1','23R2','23R2','23R2','23R2','23R2',
                '23R2','23R2','23R2','23R3','23R3','23R3','23R3','23R3',
                '23R3','23R3','23R3','23R5','23R5','23R5','23R5','23R5',
                '23R5','23R5','23R5','23R6','23R6','23R6','23R6','23R6',
                '23R6','23R6','23R6','23R7','23R7','23R7','23R7','23R8',
                '23R8','23R8','23R8','23R8','23R8','23R8','23VP','23VP',
                '23VP','23VP','23X1','23X1','23X1','23X1','23X2','23X2',
                '23X2','23X2','23X3','23X3','23X3','23X3','23X4','23X4',
                '23X4','23X4','23XX','23XX','23XX','23XX','24MA','24MA',
                '24MA','24MB','24MB','24MB','24MG','24MG','24MQ','24MQ',
                '24MQ','24MR','24MR','24MR','26R2','26R2','26R4','26R4',
                '299T','299T','299T','29R1','29R1','29R1','29R2','29R2',
                '29R2','29R3','29R3','29R4','29R4','29R4','3071','3071',
                '3071','3071','3072','3072','3072','3072','3075','3075',
                '3075','3075','3083','3083','3083','3083','3084','3084',
                '3084','3084','30XB','30XB','30XB','30XB','32M2','32M2',
                '32M2','32M2','32M2','32M3','32M3','32M3','32M3','32M3',
                '32M4','32M4','32M4','32M4','32M4','32M5','32M5','32M5',
                '32M5','32M5','32M6','32M6','32M6','32M6','32M6','32M7',
                '32M7','32M7','32M7','32M7','32M8','32M8','32M8','32M8',
                '32M8','32MB','32MB','32MB','32MB','32MB','32MD','32MD',
                '32MD','32MD','32MD','32ME','32ME','32ME','32ME','32ME',
                '32MF','32MF','32MF','32MF','32MF','32MG','32MG','32MG',
                '32MG','32MG','32MH','32MH','32MH','32MH','32MH','32MJ',
                '32MJ','32MJ','32MJ','32MJ','32MK','32MK','32MK','32MK',
                '32MK','32ML','32ML','32ML','32ML','32ML','32MM','32MM',
                '32MM','32MM','32MM','32MN','32MN','32MN','32MN','32MN',
                '32MP','32MP','32MP','32MP','32MP','32MV','32MV','32MV',
                '32MV','32MV','32MW','32MW','32MW','32MW','32MW','32R2',
                '32R2','32R2','32R2','32R2','32R3','32R3','32R3','32R3',
                '32R3','32R4','32R4','32R4','32R4','32R4','32R5','32R5',
                '32R5','32R5','32R5','32R6','32R6','32R6','32R6','32R6',
                '32R7','32R7','32R7','32R7','32R7','32R8','32R8','32R8',
                '32R8','32R8','32RA','32RA','32RA','32RA','32RA','32RB',
                '32RB','32RB','32RB','32RB','32RC','32RC','32RC','32RC',
                '32RC','32RD','32RD','32RD','32RD','32RD','32RE','32RE',
                '32RE','32RE','32RE','32RF','32RF','32RF','32RF','32RF',
                '32RG','32RG','32RG','32RG','32RG','32RH','32RH','32RH',
                '32RH','32RH','32RJ','32RJ','32RJ','32RJ','32RJ','32RK',
                '32RK','32RK','32RK','32RK','32RL','32RL','32RL','32RL',
                '32RL','32RM','32RM','32RM','32RM','32RM','32RN','32RN',
                '32RN','32RN','32RN','32RP','32RP','32RP','32RP','32RP',
                '32RQ','32RQ','32RQ','32RQ','32RQ','32RW','32RW','32RW',
                '32RW','32RW','341R','341R','341R','35R1','35R1','35R1',
                '35R1','35R2','35R2','35R2','35R3','35R3','35R3','35R3',
                '39Z1','4175','4175','4175','4175','4176','4176','4176',
                '4176','4177','4177','4177','4177','4179','4179','4179',
                '4179','41U1','41U1','41U1','41U1','41U2','41U2','41U2',
                '41U2','41U3','41U3','41U3','41U3','41U4','41U4','41U4',
                '41U4','41Z1','41Z1','41Z1','41Z1','4290','4290','4290',
                '4290','4293','4293','4293','4293','42B7','42B7','42B7',
                '42N7','42N7','42N7','42N7','4350','4350','4350','4351',
                '4351','4351','4390','4390','4390','4390','4391','4391',
                '4391','4391','43C9','43C9','43C9','43C9','44R1','44R1',
                '44R1','44R1','46MM','46MM','46MM','46R1','46R1','46R1',
                '46R2','46R2','46R2','46R2','489B','489B','48R1','48R1',
                '48R3','48R3','5185','5185','5279','5279','5279','5297',
                '5297','5297','521U','521U','521U','52R1','52R1','52R1',
                '53R1','53R1','53R1','53R1','53R2','53R2','53R2','53R2',
                '53R4','53R4','53R4','53R4','53R6','53R6','53R6','53R6',
                '53R7','53R7','53R7','53R7','5480','5480','5481','5481',
                '5482','5482','5501','5501','5501','5501','5501','5501',
                '5501','5501','5501','5502','5502','5502','5502','5502',
                '5502','5502','5502','5502','5502','5503','5503','5503',
                '5503','5503','5503','5503','5503','5503','5503','55X6',
                '55X6','55X6','55X6','560X','560X','560X','560X','561X',
                '561X','561X','561X','56PP','56PP','56PP','56PP','62R2',
                '62R2','65BT','65BT','65Z1','65Z1','65Z1','2R88','2R88',
                '2S50','2S50','2S99','2S99','3E99','3E99','3E99','3E99',
                '3EL1','3EL1','3EL1','3EL1'); -- Initialise it
BEGIN
   for i in 1..array.count loop
    for r_LRD_IORG IN (select * from LRDLicnse.LRD_IORG where IORG_TYP_DSC = 'BRANCH' and Record_status = 'A' and LGCY_IORG_ID = array(i)) loop   
      dbms_output.put_line(i, array(i), r_LRD_IORG.PS_ORG_ID);
    end loop;
   end loop;
END
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 97, column 0:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
The symbol ";" was substituted for "end-of-file" to continue.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

If you could help getting this pl/sql block up and running I would be much appreciative about it.

Thank you,

Steve Brooks

Comment: Thank you for the solutions you provided for my pl/sql script. They solved my proplems and  my script now runs great.

Comment: UGH!  Is that long list of values in 'array' _ever_ going to be subject to change?  I'd _strongly_ recommend those values be put in a table.  Then your FOR loop would be 'for i in (select col_name from my_ref_table) loop '

Comment: Excellent suggestion, we are converting from an older AS400 database to an Oracle database and they provided an Excel spreadsheet of the data. So, this is more of a one time conversion to the Peoplesoft Id. But, putting the initial data in a table would clean up the script and provide historical documentation of how the PeopleSoft Ids where generated.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obvious error, which causes this exception to be thrown: The `END` command, before the slash on a line by itself, must be ended in semicolon. Like this:

```
........
  end loop;
END;              -- notice the semicolon
/
```

After you fix this, you will run into another error. `put_line` takes only one argument, not three. If you want a string including those bits of data, and commas and spaces, you will have to build it using single-quotes for the parts that are hard-coded (comma, space) and the concatenation operator. The more common way would be something like this:

```
........
dbms_output.put_line('i = ' || i || ', array(i) = '  || array(i) ||
                                    ', PS_ORG_ID = ' || r.LRD_IORG.PS_ORG_ID);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solutions you provided for my pl/sql script. They solved my proplems and my script now runs great